# How to determine dimensions of its eigenspaces of unknown matrix from its characteristic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the following characteristic equation
$$
\lambda^3 (\lambda^2-5\lambda-6)
$$
Is it possible to determine the **exact** dimensions of its eigenspaces without knowing the actual matrix? Obviously, the $\lambda=0$ has geometric multiplicity $\leq$ 3 (i.e. where 3 is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda=0$)

Comment: The characteristic polynomial factors as $\lambda^3(\lambda+1)(\lambda-6)$

Comment: @marwalix I'm aware of this. Obviously, for $\lambda=-1$ its eigenspace is one. Same for $\lambda=6$, its eigenspace is one.

Comment: this is the maximum we can get from the characteristic polynomial. The eigenspace associated to $0$ can have dimension $1$, $2$ or $3$

Comment: @marwalix but I'm asking about the exact dimensions.

Comment: And I’m saying you cannot conclude. Let me give an example for each case $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$ dimension of the $0$ eigenspace is $3$

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$ dimension is $1$

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$ dimension is $2$

Comment: @marwalix what are these matrices you've constructed?

Comment: These matrices all have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3(\lambda+1)(\lambda-6)$ and the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $0$ has dimension $3$, $1$, and $2$. So knowing the polynomial doesn’t allow you to conclude on the dimension of the eigenspace if you don’t know the matrix